# Chroma key with cropped video on top and background images/videos with alpha blending

Tags: chromakey, lightworks

Check the following screenshot to understand what's my goal:

[image: Croma key]

I can't figure out how can I crop chroma key-recorded video, use a blend effect to make the chroma key part absolutely transparent (excepting me!), and then let the background layers (either video and images) fill the transparent part.